# How to configure the publish address of elasticsearch 5.0 with CLI flags?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, elasticsearch-5

I've used elasticsearch 2.0 with start up flags to configure the publish_addres. I need the publish address to be configured, because I want to start elasticsearch in a docker container and access it from outside. So the publish address must be the IP of the docker host, which is in my case 192.168.99.100. I want to access elasticsearch on port 9201.

```
docker run -d -p 9201:9201 --name elasticsearch_test elasticsearch:5.2-alpine elasticsearch -Enetwork.publish_host="192.168.99.100" -Ehttp.port="9201"
```

which is like the old command

```
docker run -d -p 9201:9201 --name elasticsearch_test elasticsearch:2.4.1 elasticsearch -Des.network.publish_host="192.168.99.100" -Des.http.port="9201"
```

But when I start the container and look into the logs I don't get the publish address 192.168.99.100:9201, but 192.168.99.100:9300 and 172.17.0.2:9201. How can I force elasticsearch to use my combination of address and port?

Thanks in advance

Output of `docker logs elasticsearch_test`

```
[2017-02-13T09:17:03,095][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-02-13T09:17:03,252][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ntIFoHQ] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [1gb], net total_space [17.8gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
[2017-02-13T09:17:03,252][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [ntIFoHQ] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-02-13T09:17:03,253][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [ntIFoHQ] derived from node ID [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-02-13T09:17:03,257][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.2.0], pid[1], build[24e05b9/2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z], OS[Linux/4.4.43-boot2docker/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_111-internal/25.111-b14]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,249][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,250][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,251][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,251][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,251][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,251][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,251][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,251][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,254][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [ntIFoHQ] no plugins loaded
[2017-02-13T09:17:05,677][WARN ][o.e.d.s.g.GroovyScriptEngineService] [groovy] scripts are deprecated, use [painless] scripts instead
[2017-02-13T09:17:10,757][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-02-13T09:17:10,757][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ntIFoHQ] starting ...
[2017-02-13T09:17:11,015][WARN ][i.n.u.i.MacAddressUtil   ] Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: 07:0a:ef:37:62:95:b2:77
[2017-02-13T09:17:11,198][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [ntIFoHQ] publish_address {192.168.99.100:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-02-13T09:17:11,203][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [ntIFoHQ] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-02-13T09:17:14,351][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [ntIFoHQ] new_master {ntIFoHQ}{ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q}{cW1MZt0-RmutLXz_Tkm8mw}{192.168.99.100}{192.168.99.100:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-02-13T09:17:14,395][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [ntIFoHQ] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9201}, bound_addresses {[::]:9201}
[2017-02-13T09:17:14,396][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ntIFoHQ] started
[2017-02-13T09:17:14,423][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [ntIFoHQ] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2017-02-13T09:17:44,398][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:17:44,398][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2017-02-13T09:18:14,434][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:18:44,438][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:18:44,438][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2017-02-13T09:19:14,443][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:19:44,446][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:19:44,447][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2017-02-13T09:20:14,453][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:20:44,459][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:20:44,459][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2017-02-13T09:21:14,467][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:21:44,471][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:21:44,471][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2017-02-13T09:22:14,482][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:22:44,485][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2017-02-13T09:22:44,485][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] rerouting shards: [high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes]
[2017-02-13T09:23:14,497][WARN ][o.e.c.r.a.DiskThresholdMonitor] [ntIFoHQ] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [ntIFoHQnTAahC7_0cEt32Q][ntIFoHQ][/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0] free: 1gb[5.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `http.publish_host=192.168.99.100` in conjunction with `http.port`